# Не работает Aiogram3

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, бот, aiogram-3.x

### Описание

---

Новый Aiogram3 версии 3.0.0b7. Бот не реагирует на сообщения, а только выводит логи в консоль (Я так понял бот не может получить обновления от сервера).
Версия Python: 3.10.9

### Лог

---

```
Failed to fetch updates - TelegramConflictError: Conflict: can't use getUpdates method while webhook is active; use deleteWebhook to delete the webhook first
Sleep for 1.000000 seconds and try again... (tryings = 0, bot id = 5082045144)
```

И т.д.

### Код

---

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.types import Message
import asyncio

token = "<token>"


async def get_start(message: Message, bot: Bot):
    await message.reply(f"Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}!")


async def start():
    bot = Bot(token=token)

    dp = Dispatcher()
    dp.message.register(get_start)

    try:
        await dp.start_polling(bot)
    finally:
        await bot.session.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(start())
```

Как можно исправить эту проблему с ботом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас **WebHook** включен, `getUpdates` не работает когда он включен, отключите при помощи

`await bot.delete_webhook()`